# get date range between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table tbl in database and I have dynamic joining date 1-1-2012 and I want this date is between (Fall and spring) or (spring and summer) or (summer and fall).I want query in which i passed only joining date which return semestertime and joining date in Oracle.

```
Semestertime        joiningDate
Fall            10-13-2011 
Spring          2-1-2012
Summer          6-11-2012
Fall            10-1-2015
```

Comment: Given `1-1-2012` this will return `fall 2011` ? And what if given `1-1-2015` ?

Comment: i want query how can i find date what ever i give range

Comment: i have dynamic joining date

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE joiningDate between to_date (your_lower_limit_date_here, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
AND to_date (your_upper_limit_date_here, 'mm-dd-yyyy`);
```

Comment: i have above table and only one joining date how can i write query.How can i find what is lower limit and what is upper limi?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that:

```
select 'BEFORE' term,
        t."Semestertime", to_char(t."joiningDate", 'MM-DD-YYYY')
from (
  select tbl.*, rownum rn from tbl where tbl."joiningDate" < to_date('1-1-2012','MM-DD-YYYY')
  --                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  --                                                           your reference date
  order by tbl."joiningDate" desc) t
where rn = 1

union all

select 'AFTER' term,
        t."Semestertime", to_char(t."joiningDate", 'MM-DD-YYYY')
from (
  select tbl.*, rownum rn from tbl where tbl."joiningDate" > to_date('1-1-2012','MM-DD-YYYY')
  --                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  --                                                           your reference date

  order by tbl."joiningDate" asc) t
where rn = 1
```

This will return the "term" before and after a given date. You will probably have to adapt such query to your specific needs. But that might be a good starting point.

For example, given your business rules, you might consider using `<=` instead of `<`. You you might require to have the result displayer a column instead of rows. Bu all of this shouldn't be too had to change.

---

As an alternate solution using CTE and sub-queries:

```
with testdata as (select to_date('1-1-2012','MM-DD-YYYY') refdate from dual)

select v.what, tbl.* from tbl join
(
  select 'BEFORE' what, max(t1."joiningDate") d
  from tbl t1
  where t1."joiningDate" < to_date('1-1-2012','MM-DD-YYYY')

  union all

  select 'AFTER' what, min(t1."joiningDate") d
  from tbl t1
  where t1."joiningDate" > to_date('1-1-2012','MM-DD-YYYY')
) v
on tbl."joiningDate" = v.d
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7fa5/15 for a live demo comparing those solutions.